# Can i create a framework with classes,xib and image and use it another project as a framework?

Tags: iphone, ios, ios4

Can i create a framework with classes,nib and image and use it another project as a framework?

Answer (score 1):

You can create an static library where you will put the code an a bundle where you will put your resources.

Static library tutorial [here](http://www.icodeblog.com/2011/04/07/creating-static-libraries-for-ios/).